# General type input of function

Tags: system-verilog

I have a UVM project. I have the following code in my test_base:

```
class test_base extends uvm_test;
   //factory registration
   `uvm_component_utils(test_base)

   //internal decleration
   girobo2_env grb_env_i;

   //configuration objects:
   grb2_env_config    m_env_cfg;
   axi_agent_config   m_axi_agent_cfg;

   .........

   //build_phase
   //Create axi_agent agent configuration object
   m_axi_agent_cfg = axi_agent_config::type_id::create("m_axi_agent_cfg");
   if(!uvm_config_db #(virtual axi_interface)::get(this, "", "axi_vif", m_axi_agent_cfg.axi_vif) 
      `uvm_error("RESOURCE_ERROR", "axi_interface virtual interface not found")
   m_env_cfg.m_axi_agent_cfg = m_axi_agent_cfg; 
   // Call function to configure the axi  agent
   configure_axi_agent(m_axi_agent_cfg);

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   // configure_my_agent
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Convenience function to configure the agent
   // This can be overloaded by extensions to this base class
   virtual function void configure_axi_agent (axi_agent_config cfg);
      cfg.is_active = UVM_PASSIVE;    
   endfunction: configure_my_agent
endclass: test_base
```

Is there an option to define the type of the input of the `configure_my_agent` function general (like template in c++ for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the input type of `configure_my_agent` to a generic `uvm_object`. Then, you can pass any `uvm_object` in and cast it appropriately.

```
virtual function void configure_my_agent (uvm_object base_cfg);

  if (base_cfg.get_type_name == "grb2_env_config") begin
    axi_agent_config cfg;
    $cast(cfg, base_cfg);
    cfg.is_active = UVM_PASSIVE;
  end
  else if (base_cfg.get_type_name == "grb2_env_config") begin
    grb2_env_config cfg;
    $cast(cfg, base_cfg);
    cfg.is_active = UVM_PASSIVE;
  end
  else if ...... // All other config type names 

endfunction: configure_my_agent
```

**NOTE:**
Personally, I don't like this method. `is_active` is of type `UVM_ACTIVE_PASSIVE_ENUM` and should be directly set from the base test for each agent in the build phase. Then in the build_phase of the agent, you look up this variable and decide if your agent is active or passive. Note that for this to work, you should register the `is_active` variable with in the `uvm_component_utils of your agent (UVM components automagically look up registered class variables during its build_phase).

Comment: how do you use if on "cgf" if it has not defined yet?

Comment: I changed the cfg in the if to base_cfg.  I got the following error: # ** Error (suppressible): ..\sv\test_base.sv(109): (vlog-7027) The name ('cfg')
 was not found in the current scope.  Please verify the spelling of the name 'cf
g'.

Comment: have you defined `cfg` in the current scope of the base test?

Comment: @noobuntu- I have axi_agent_cfg, tx_agent_cfg, and rx_agent_cfg in the test scope.

Comment: I made an obvious mistake. `cfg` is only available in limited scope since it is declared within the `begin end` block. Try the updated code and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The UVM factory provides a mechanism used for specifying type overrides that can also be used to check the type.

The static method `axi_agent_config::type_id::get_type()` returns a handle to a proxy singleton object that represents the type of `axi_agent_config`. You can call the virtual `uvm_object` method `get_object_type()` that returns a handle to a proxy singleton object that represents the type of the *actual* object passed to `cfg`. So you can write

```
if (axi_agent_config::type_id::get_type() == cfg.get_object_type() )
   // then you have a matching base class object
else if (axi_extended_agent_cdg::type_id::get_type() == cfg.get_object_type() )
   // then you have a matching extended object
```

Comment: @dave_59- But what should be the param of the general function (from which type)?

Comment: Use a common base type

Comment: # ** at ..\sv\test_base.sv(157):  Failed to find name 'get_type' in specified scope.    The relevant line is:  if (axi_agent_config::type_id::get_type() == cfg.get_object_type() )

Comment: Use a common base type that is registered with the factory.

Comment: -and got the following error:  ** Error: ** while parsing file included at ../sv/girobo2_ver_pkg.sv(30)
 ** at ..\sv\test_base.sv(157):  Failed to find name 'get_type' in specified scope